# Stop waiting for serial response after 5 seconds in Python

Tags: python, serial-port, wait

I am trying to get a **response** from a serial port, but sometimes there will be **none**. This makes my script wait **forever**, thus I have to kill it.

Is there a **simple** way to make my code wait for example 5 seconds and if there was no response continue with the script?

My code looks like this:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)

test = '2ho0'

ser.write(str.encode(test))
data = ser.readline()
print(data)
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657278/python-stop-a-thread-after-n-seconds) solution, but it does not stop after 5 prints of `Hello world`. Instead, it continues writing `Hello World`, until I get a `runtime error`.

Over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802270/python-how-to-stop-a-function) I tried severeal answers with no success either.

EDIT: I am wondering if it is possible to have something like:

```
ser.serialReplyAvailable()
```

This would do the job for me as well.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I think the asyncio module (specificaly the `Task` class) is what you're looking for. This can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710835/proper-way-to-shutdown-asyncio-tasks

Comment: I thought that `SIGNAL` only works correctly on unix. Since I am on Windows, this is unfortunately not working. I get the error `signal has no attribute SIGHUP`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a read timeout which will make the `ser.readline()` either return immediately if the requested data is available, or return whatever was read until the timeout expired. Check the pySerial docs there is more on this there.

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping the readline into a while Statement and have a timer tick inside if the reading was not successful. If it is, break out of it.

```
from time import sleep
tries = 0
while tries < 4:
    data = ser.readline()
    if data != None: #Or "", whatever the return data
        break
    sleep(5); tries += 1
```

Comment: This does not help since the script is stuck at `data = ser.readline()`.

Comment: ah, so you are not getting "None" returned, you just get no response at all. That is indeed more tricky. The only thing I can think of is maybe if you use a new thread and then shut that down after a certain amount of time has passed?